Maximum number of consecutive primitive and non-primitive roots
Let $q$ be a prime.
Is there any conjecture on maximum number for $k$ before which we hit a non-primitive root in the sequence $a$, $a+1$,$\dots$,$a+k$ where $a+i$ is primitive root for all $i\in\{0,1,\dots,k-1\}$?
Is there any conjecture on maximum number for $k$ before which we hit a primitive root in the sequence $a$, $a+1$,$\dots$,$a+k$ where $a+i$ is non-primitive root for all $i\in\{0,1,\dots,k-1\}$?
